# Simulate a login to succesfully POST to a diffrent page

Tags: laravel, curl, cookies, x-xsrf-token

We have a self-hosted **snipe-it** instance. Sadly at the moment API-token creation is only possible via Website and we are waiting for the [feature](https://github.com/snipe/snipe-it/issues/10648).

In the mean time we trying to achieve the API-token creation via a different approach:

Since the API-token creation on the webpage shows on the web-console only a single `POST` command against the url `http://my-snipit-instance/oauth/personal-access-tokens` after clicking the button "Create New Token" and entering a name into the popup field. The POST includes following request content:

```json
{
   "name":"Test",
   "scopes":[],
   "errors":[]
}
```

and as repsonse content this:

```json
{
    "accessToken":"ey*****",
    "token":{
        "id":"f347******",
        "user_id":1,
        "client_id":1,
        "name":"Test",
        "scopes":[],
        "revoked":false,
        "created_at":"2022-09-28 15:36:24",
        "updated_at":"2022-09-28 15:36:24",
        "expires_at":"2037-09-28T13:36:24.000000Z"
    }
}
```

Additional the header included for the request 2 cookies:

- snipeit_session
- XSRF-TOKEN

As far as I understand the XSRF TOKEN prevents an XSRF attack on the server. Since the post request does not use any other authorization, I think the XSRF-TOKEN is responsible to give me access to the laravel-backend function which creates the API-Token.

Now I have the problem that I don't really understand where the XSRF-TOKEN is created. We used the login page of snipe-it to analyze the `GET` and `POST` commands. I am somehow sure, that the `GET` against `http://my-snipit-instance/login` is resposible for the initialization since the `POST` against this url uses the credentials.

Later we will use `python` for the relevant commands but at the moment `curl` will satisfy.

**EDIT 1:**
At the moment  I think a simple `curl -b cookies -c cookies <URL>` will satisfy. The only thing which I am unable to wrap my head around, the payload for `POST` against the `http://my-snipit-instance/login` looks the following:

```json
{
    "_token": "**********", # HERE IS WHAT TOKEN?
    "prevent_autofill: ''",
    "password_fake: ''",
    "username": "webuser",
    "password": "1234567890"
}
```

The entry `_token` seems the important part, but I do not understand, from where the request is getting this value.

Comment: `XSRF-TOKEN` seems irrelevant. You can just do the API calls with an access token. Take a look at [Authenticating with the API | SNIPE](https://snipe-it.readme.io/reference/authenticating-with-the-api) and how to actually do API calls to it (listed in the assets section same page). They also explain how to [generate API tokens](https://snipe-it.readme.io/reference/generating-api-tokens)

Comment: What you refer to is true and I know about the API-Token creation. Actually the `POST` against `http://my-snipit-instance/oauth/personal-access-tokens` happens on the page the second link refers against. Our Issue: We develop a app which uses the API and a User should not (if allowed) create the Token him/herself, instead the backend creates the token after authentication and delete the token again. Sadly something like [this](https://postgrest.org/en/stable/auth.html#client-auth) is not implemented until now.